# OpenGL transforming the normals

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm new to OpenGL, I'm using 4.6.0 version.
I have a model composed of different figures.
When lighting is applied the normal are screwed.
I have try to read documentation, in theory, all I have to do is multiply by the inverse of the transpose and the reescale the normals.
On this forum

> http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_normaltransform.html
> advise to have two models view, one for the transformations of the model and other to store only the rotations for the normals.

The problem is that I dont know how to define a seccond modelview or any kind of matrix, or transpose th glModelView.
Thanks.

Comment: Please show your shader and relevant code. Are you really using 4.6? Because glModelView doesn't look like modern GL.

Comment: If you're using OpenGL 4.6 (core profile), then you use `glUniformMatrix` to set the uniform variables in the shader unit. But i suppose, that you want to use the compatibility profile (OpenGL 2.x)? Modern OpenGL does not know/care about Modelview or Projection matrices, there are only matrices, how they are utilized is up to the developer (via shader code). Have a look at https://learnopengl.com/ **or** https://open.gl/ **and** https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/ **and** https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/